# Terrain for gamedevelopement, how to paint it?

Tags: asset

My experience level: around 8 years and always hated nodes, never used them avoided them like hell cause found everything about node logic to be counterintuitive and illogical and insesical, plus they pretty much change everything almost every few updates, I've always just used stencil painting to color my blends.

but I'm trying to make a small map, an isle of a few kilometers, split in small UV's of a few hundred meters each.

Every tutorial on youtube either does it by hand painting every single piece of dirt or uses some kind of masks that then I have no idea how would they even export all that stuff to a game engine, the stuff they show on youtube or blender reddit in general always seem like useless assets that would only work in blender and serve no purpose outside blender.

so is there a way to paint terrain for gamedev that actually exports?

[image]

Comment: Hello, if you don't feel comfortable with materials in Blender you can do it with a software like Substance Painter, Quixel, Armorpaint, etc. If you do it in Blender, you can use Image Texture as masks, then bake to an unique Image Texture, or use brush masks, etc

Comment: Some major game engines also have their own tools to handle terrains, might be worth a look in that direction.